# Difference between `npm link x` and `npm install /path/to/x`

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-link

I thought I understood the difference between

```
npm link x
```

and

```
npm install /local/path/to/x
```

originally I thought the former created a symlink to x, whereas the latter installed a separate copy of x in your project, instead of symlinking it.

However, I recently noticed that my original impression was wrong, and they both seem to use symlinks - so is there a difference between the two and what is it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[An article on Medium](https://medium.com/@oresoftware/node-js-how-to-test-your-new-npm-module-without-publishing-it-every-5-minutes-3b6f8e0491dd) by Alex Mills lays it out bare.

It says the difference between `npm link x` and `npm install /local/path/to/x` are:

1. The big difference is that `npm install /local/path/x` will
   run the preinstall/postinstall hooks, but `npm link x` will not.
2. `npm link` uses the global NPM space, `npm install /local/path/x` does not. npm link creates a symlink to x
   in the global space, and then when you call npm link x from
   y, it creates a symlink not directly to x, but rather to
   the global symlink. This is an important differences if you are
   using different global node.js versions, e.g., NVM.
3. `npm install /absolute/path/x` will alter package.json, `npm link x`
   does not.

To get a fresh local copy instead of a symlink, use `npm pack`, like so:

```
tgz="$PWD/$(npm pack)"
cd <other project>
npm install "$tgz"
```

You could also use cp/rsync, but that wouldn't run install hooks or put the executables in `node_modules/.bin`...that will work.

Comment: it's not my article, it must be a different guy named Alex Mills, weird didn't notice that before, happy with the credit tho!

Comment: Hah! Imagine that! Sorry, I shouldn't give you the credit, then. Corrected. Cheers!

Comment: It sounds like `npm link` can be used with Git friends and `npm install /absolute/local/path` cannot.

Comment: the medium link is broken :(

Answer (score 9):

## `npm link`

```
npm link
npm link <folder>
```

Both of the above command will create a symlink of the `<folder>` in the global packages.

Now `npm link <folder>` will symlink the same in your `node_modules` folder also for your current project. And these names would be based on project name in `package.json` and not based on the folder name you are linking

The `package.json` of your current project will not be touched or altered

The dependencies of the package will still be installed as you can see in the code here

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/31d5bdea70e44802918d6f4aa7c378bc1992be54/deps/npm/lib/link.js#L156

So to summarize:

1. It creates a symlink in the global folder (always).
2. It doesn't alter the `package.json`.
3. It does install any of missing dependencies.

## `npm install`

Now `npm install <folder>` is a bit different to this:

1. It doesn't create a symlink in the global folder.
2. It alters and adds the reference to `package.json`.
3. It creates a symlink to original folder.