# Installing component from folder doesn't work but works from tarball

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have Project and Component (both React based). Both are local and i do not want to publish them yet. I'm trying to include the Component into the Project by installing it with `npm i`.

In case i try to install the Component from tarball `npm i file:../component-1.0.0.tgz` (after `npm pack`) everything works as expected.
In case i try to install it from the folder `npm i file:../component` i get error at project start:
`ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/home/user/www/component/lib`
React is the peer-dependency in the Component, obviously.

I want to modify the Component during the development of the Project. How can i install the Component from the folder?
**Please do not suggest me to import Component from the source, this is important to not modify any line in the Project.**

Comment: Perhaps consider utilizing [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html) instead.

Comment: `npm i file:../folder` in fact does exactly `npm link` does. This is not the solution.

Comment: See [difference between `npm link x` and `npm install /path/to/x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674052/difference-between-npm-link-x-and-npm-install-path-to-x). Presumably when you say both are _"exactly"_ you mean they both give you the same error ?

Comment: Yes, i know the difference, but for my question this doesn't matter. The problem is that if copy the Component into node_modules everything works. If i symlink the Component, no matter how, via `npm link` or via `npm i folder`  - it doesn't.